# How does the topology of the graphs' Riemann surface relate to its knot representation?

Tags: graph-theory, riemann-surfaces, knot-theory, zeta-functions

Let me give a worked-out example: The following cubic planar [non-simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) graph

$\hskip2.3in$[image]

has the adjacency matrix $A=\pmatrix{0&3\\3&0}$. The graph has three faces, so the rank of $G$ is [$\chi(G)=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582616/of-face-and-circuit-rank). The reciprocal of Ihara's $\zeta$ function can be evaluated
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta_G(u)}={(1-u^2)^{\chi(G)-1}\det(I - Au + 2u^2I)}\\
={(1-u^2) (4u^4-5u^2+1)}
$$

**EDIT**: Then $\zeta_G(u)=\frac{(1-u^2)^{-1} }{(4u^4-5u^2+1)}=\prod_p (1-u^{L(p)})$ with the product running over prime paths $p$ and $L(p)$ being their lenghts. The $-1$ in the numerator's exponent $(1-u^2)^{-1}$ is due to $|V|-|E|=2-3=-1$...

Looking at the orientation of the edges around the vertices, it is obvious that left and right are oriented opposite.

Now blow up every edge like in a [ribbon or fat graph](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ribbon+graph). Including the change of orientation the resulting graph looks like:

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

where I stuck to the convention that I flipped every fat graph edge in the same direction. The resulting knot is a trefoil, which has the following polynomial [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot#Invariants):

> The Alexander polynomial of the trefoil knot is
> $    \Delta (t)=t-1+t^{-1},$
> and the Conway polynomial is
> $     \nabla (z)=z^{2}+1.$
> The Jones polynomial is $    V(q)=q^{-1}+q^{-3}-q^{-4}.$..

None of the latter mentioned matches Ihara's $\zeta$. My list is not complete, but

> Is there a relation between Ihara's $\zeta$ and any knot polynomial?

**EDIT**:

Further, the bicubic planar graphs can be related to Riemann surfaces (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626800/19341) and references therein). Is there a relation between the Riemann surfaces and the knot?

> How does the topology of the graphs' Riemann surface relate to its knot representation?

Comment: Do you know how to show here the $\zeta_G(s)$ obtained from the prime cycles  and the Euler product is the same as what you wrote [in term of the  adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihara_zeta_function#Ihara.27s_formula) ?

Comment: @user1952009 I think that is exactly what Ihara has proven. I tried to come from [non-backtracking paths](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/177722/19341) via Chebyshev polynmomials and think I got pretty close [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1580353/19341), but I'm still looking for answers...

Comment: It's not clear to me because $4u^4-5u^2+1 = (2u-1)(2u+1)(u+1)(u-1)$ so your $\zeta_G(u)$ is not an Euler product generating the number of cycles of a given length. Did you try normalizing the adjacency matrix ?

Comment: @user1952009 I added something to explain that.  Which matrix norm would you recommend and why? How could normalization help?

Comment: Sideremark for me: $-\log((1-x^2)(4x^4-5x^2+1))=12\frac {x^2} 2+36 \frac{x^4}4+132\frac{x^6}6+\cdots$ $12$ means: select $g,y,r$ or its inverse for the first step, so that's $6$. Then you have two other colors to go back: $6\cdot 2=12$ ...

Comment: Re-posted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/275112/11856...

Comment: I don't think we need to close this before the MO one was answered.